# VirtualBox Ubuntu 12.04 cannot open display under Superuser

Tags: virtualbox

Everytime I try to open a visual editor from the terminal as superuser, I get this error:

```
user:~$ sudo gedit
Cannot open display: 
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

However, when I open it normally, it works just fine. Any ideas?

Edit: gsuko doesn't change this behaviour either

Edit:

```
user:~$ sudo kate
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
kate: cannot connect to X server
```

Comment: this is perhaps a stupid question but: you're inside the graphical desktop when typing this, right? not in one of the other tty's?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise typing "gedit" wouldn't work either, would it?

Comment: is the issue limited to `gedit` or do other programs fail to start from the terminal with identical error message?

Comment: I reedited the post to answer this question, good point.

Comment: I've suggested a migration of this question to askubuntu. You're far more likely to get timely responses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gksudo? That's for invoking graphical Applications as superuser. Although i think sudo should work as well in normal Ubuntu.

edit: vim and nano are editors working from inside the terminal. Ubuntu should have those installed by default.

Comment: Yes, to the same result

Comment: Wim's question above is pretty relevant. Are you using the graphical terminal opened in the desktop of the virtual machine? Or one of the tty's or perhaps using ssh to log in to the machine? If all fails don't forget about vim or nano, these editors will work inside the terminal.

Comment: I know about nano and vim but I prefer a graphical editor for editing more than a line or two.